# selectbitmap() return as filename string

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

When using **selectbitmap()** and selecting an image off my desktop I get this returned **"BitMap:C:\Users\John\Pictures\image.png"**

I would like it to just give me the image's location as a string value (basically just remove the **"BitMap:"** portion of what is returned). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectBitmap` does not only select the filename, but loads the Bitmap. That is what the value you are returned represents. If you do not need to do anything with the Bitmap, you can read its `filename` property and then close it.

```
local myBmp = selectBitmap()
if (myBmp != undefined) do
(
    local myFile = myBmp.filename
    close myBmp
)
```

Comment: late reply... sorry! Thank you for taking the time to answer this!